# Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*'

Tags: ios, code-signing

Constantly receiving an error on test-flight upload as follows:

> ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements.  Your application
>   bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on   iOS. Specifically, value '*' for key
>   'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp'
>   is not supported.

Went through several associated similar stackoverflow questions but didn't got the solution yet. I am providing associated-domain value for com.apple.developer.associated-domains at capabilities as "applinks:myapp.onelink.me".
My Xcode version is 10.1 and deployment target is 11.0

Comment: Did you ever find what the issue was? @jitesh-upadhyay